# CONNECTIVITY_ACTION Receiver In Manifest

Tags: android, networking, broadcastreceiver

I need to submit some data as soon as there is an internet connection. Until now I've done this by registering a broadcast receiver in the manifest for the CONNECTIVITY_ACTION event. This works perfectly but now I'm worried about the performance.
I mean a CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcast is sent pretty often sometimes and the every time my app will be "started" just to try to submit some data, that might not even exist at that moment.

Is there a better way to do that? Or does it not really matter?
I mean I could register a receiver in every activity but that's not very neat I think. I know I could make a class derive from Activity (to override onResume and onPause) but as I'm also using FragmentActivity, that isn't the best option either.

Do you have some suggestions on how to do that? The data doesn't need to be sent immediately if a connection is available (I mean that would be very nice but not necessary).
I could also just try to send the data in the onResume method of every activity but again that's not as neat as I'd like it...

Answer (score 0):

Many apps fire up receiving that broadcast. Check the logcat yourself. Some apps have a running service that check for a connection, vomiting out exceptions.

As many times stated by Google engineers, it's less taxing on the battery to do your tasks upon radio being in active mode and do some extra for caching, than to wind up radio every few minutes. Refer to 2012 Google I/O speech by [Reto Meier](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PwC1OlJo5VM). He outlines a bit how it should work and why.